# Hint text of Material Design Component (material.textfield.TextInputLayout) is not being translated

Tags: java, android, material-design

I have developed an Android app that supports multiple languages. As per Design Library, I have used Material Design. As shown:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textField2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/password"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/teal_700"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    >
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"

        />
```

**All string values are being translated when the certain language is selected except the hint value on TextInputEditText.

```
    Any help would be much appreciated!**
```

Comment: Possibly this: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/051410b7efc089e50e7f83db9a922258e2ba359e.

Comment: Yeah, that seems likely to be the issue, as far as my tests indicate. That fix will probably be in the next release, but if you need something right now, you could handle it manually; e.g., override the `Activity`'s `onRestoreInstanceState()` method, and set the hint after the `super` call. That is, `super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);` first, then `textField2.setHint(R.string.password);`. Alternatively, if you have a bunch of them, you could create a custom `TextInputLayout` subclass instead, but that's probably not worth the effort if you only have a few.